# Create Google Calendar Event via WFR and outbound message

Tags: workflow, case, event, calendar, google-apps

What I would like to accomplish is:

Support agent enters Date/Time into a custom Date/Time field on Case.
Once the record is saved, automatically create a new event on a shared google calendar.

I am trying to accomplish this without having to write an Apex trigger, so my thought is to do this:

Create WFR that sends outbound message anytime this field is updated. Send outbound message to an internal server and process it with PHP and pass the details to another PHP script that creates the Google event.

Wondering if anyone has done something like that that can point me in the right direction on getting started (like if there are any existing PHP helper scripts that might help with this), or is this just the wrong way of going about this.

I am not a coder by nature, but can mash things together when needed, just need a boot-kick in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the outbound message in Salesforce, it will generate a WSDL for you. You should be able to use a tool that will use the WSDL to generate PHP code:  https://www.wsdltophp.com or http://sourceforge.net/projects/easywsdl2php/

There are several tools available for this so choose the one that is best for your particular case.

From here you should be able to make use of the Google API:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

And use the object that is created from your outbound message to configure your google event and insert your shared calendar.

Best of luck,  let us know if you need more of a boot-kick.